# How to "mimic" partial functions in IDP-Z3?

Tags: idp-z3

I've been coming across more and more applications that require support for partial functions in one way or another. How can I "mimic" this behavior in the current IDP-Z3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, partial functions are very common, but IDP-Z3 does not support them at the moment. Here are some common modelling approaches to partial functions in a language that does not natively support them:

1. Model `n`-ary partial function as `n+1`-ary predicate. Let's say that you have function `f : Nat -> Nat` mapping natural numbers to natural numbers which is partial. You can instead introduce `Gf : nat x nat` predicate. In addition you would have to add a uniqueness axiom to your theory, stating that for each natural number there is at most one tuple in `Gf: ! x[Nat] y[Nat] z[Nat] : Gf(x,y) & Gf(x,z) => y = z.`. This method has a downside that you can not use your function as a term in some expressions e.g. `P(f(3))` but you would have to introduce a new variable: `! x[Nat] : Gf(3,x) => P(x).` or `? x[Nat] : Gf(3,x) & P(x).`. Note that these two are the same if there is some `x` such that `Gf(3,x)` but otherwise the first one is `true` and the second statement is `false`.
2. Introduce a new element in a type to represent undefinedness. This is usually dangerous since in any a bit bigger application things can easily get out of control since you might end up having many different symbols representing undefined (i.e., one per type).
3. Sometimes it is possible to narrow your type and make your function total. However, this is also a very case-specific approach that can not be used in general in IDP-Z3.

[Here](https://interactive-consultant.idp-z3.be/IDE?gist=f57127852b5a6b48574c934850198975&file=Graph_of_partial_function_example) is the simple example employing the first approach.